# Getting error when connecting to an app using Intuit

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have just created an app in **Customer Account Data** section in

https://developer.intuit.com after signup.

Then I created a .NET application to get authorization after providing the details, I received just after app was successfully created like **consumerKey** and **consumerSecret**.

I am able to get the page that authenticate with my username but there is also an error like :

> Oops! An error has occurred. 
>   Please close this window and try again. 
>   Error Code: invalid_database 
>   Message: AppId cannot be <= 0, appId=-1

My main aim is to get back to the page which shows a successful authentication. I again checked my app in

https://developer.intuit.com/Application/List

and I see  **Status: Pending Review** for that app.

I just want to test the authentication for a sample application.

How can I understand this review system? Do we have something like sandbox in PayPal for testing, and if so, how to get started with it?

Answer (score 2):

Are you *100% positive* that you have your OAuth key, secret, and your app token correctly entered in the config for your app?

You should not need to go through any sort of review process - you probably just have something entered/configured incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for the reply @consolibyte. you are right. I was getting that name because I was logged in with the site in other pages, 

The code I used to redirect doesn't used any detail I got. Here is my link with the values.

  string oauthLink = "https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin" +   "?oauth_token=" + "qyprdY64Wdhabdsf7r7UTTH1Yo89wxQd1xpTaFmOsLteJ9MTp"
+  "&oauth_callback=" + UriUtility.UrlEncode("http://localhost:6430/Successful.aspx");

  Response.Redirect(oauthLink); 

can u plz help me in how to create a right link with the consumerkey, consumerSecret and SAML Identity Provider ID

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused between apps for Customer Account Data and Quickbooks.
If you created an app for CAD, then you need to upload a certificate too. 
If you go to GITHUB sample app for CAD-
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code->customer account data

You will see that it does not require the oauth callback url or any of the values, you have mentioned. All these values are required when you create a quickbooks sample application.

The above link has both the code samples for CAD as well as Quickbooks.
Please verify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you were using wrong public-private key pair.

While setting up AggCat intergration, you had used one public key, but while doing SAML assertion you are not using the corresponding .key/.p12 file. Please verify that.

You can easily test this use case using APIExplorer tool.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData

You can refer the following steps to get new tokens and test API calls.

Key generation using openssl - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

After generating these keys, you can create a sample app with the public key. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0015_create_an_cad_integration

then use the .p12 file with pwd for SAML assertion in apiexplorer Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

Thanks